# Create a for loop that generates individual emails with html dataframe for each unique recipient

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a for loop that creates individual emails with html dataframe for each unique recipient (using the first column).

the dataframe looks like this:

[image: dataframe]

Expected output:

[image: Email one]

[image: Email two]

My current code:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
email = (row['Email Address'])
subject = (row['Subject'])
table = df.iloc[:, 2:].to_html(index = False)
olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = subject

newMail.HTMLbody = ( '''
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <p>Hi All,</p>
        <p>{TABLE}</p>
        <p>Best Regards,</p>
    </body>
</html>'''.format(TABLE = table))

newMail.To = email
newMail.display()
```

Comment: What's the output of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the table grouped by unique emails, you'll need to use groupby:

```
grp = df.groupby('email') #group data by email
sent_mail = [] #store emails to which messages have been sent here
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['email'] in sent_mail: #check if mail has already been sent to prevent sending multile mails
        pass
    else:
        email = (row['email'])
        sent_mail.append(email)
        subject = (row['subject'])
        table = grp.get_group(email).to_html(index = False)
        olMailItem = 0x0
        obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
        newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        newMail.Subject = subject

        newMail.HTMLbody = ( '''
        <html>
        <head>
        </head>
            <body>
                <p>Hi All,</p>
                <p>{TABLE}</p>
                <p>Best Regards,</p>
            </body>
        </html>'''.format(TABLE = table))

        newMail.To = email
        newMail.display()
```

Comment: Hello Seyi, The script works like a charm, however i got double emails in the second email address (TestTwo@xyz.com), could be that check is not working properly.

Comment: sorry, i omitted a line in my code. I've edited my answer now, you can try it again

Comment: Thanks Seyi its working perfectly, you saved me lots of time in this task :)